# Regex for List of numbers

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am trying to validate a xml schema by giving restriction in xsd. The schema has 
555-333-4834,444-233-3333 which could contain either one or several phone numbers.

This is my solution:

```
<xs:element name="PhoneNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:maxLength value="14"></xs:maxLength>
               <xs:minLength value="10"></xs:minLength>
               <xs:pattern value="^[0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{4})?"></xs:pattern>
           </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
```

Aim is to check if first 3 are digits. I tried to test with this. It works fine for 1 number but not for list of numbers.

Comment: You can check the regular expression with this web https://regex101.com/ . Also you have to know that parenthesis are for creating groups, maybe this is working bad. Also you can try to escape the '-' because you can have problems because it is also used for ranges of letters or numbers.

Comment: I didn't get the **list of numbers** part. Does it mean that it should accept 555-333-4834,444-233-3333? But the max length allowed seems to be 14 only.

Comment: If any of the phone numbers are non-US numbers, then this is a hopeless plan. Surely even in the US, it is becoming more common for people to have contact with foreigners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all phone numbers must be exactly in the format you posted (nnn-nnn-nnnn), this regex will match one or more, separated by commas (no leading/trailing comma allowed):

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}(,\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})*$
```

If leading/trailing commas are to be allowed, the pattern is:

```
^,?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}(,\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})*,?$
```

Comment: Thank You @aaron_world_traveler

Answer (score 0):

This one does the work:
`^([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})(,[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})*$`

It works for one or many comma-separated phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

the restriction maxLength = 14 avoid the presence of more than one telephone number. Also, you must modify the pattern as @aaron_world_traveler and @Paco Abato suggest in his answers.

By the way, with your current schema, you can use several PhoneNumber tags with one number each.

Comment: Thanks I will definetly take it into consideration @jmad